# Malformed HTTP Request

Tags: vb.net, laravel

Any reason why I am getting 'Malformed HTTP Request' from server?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ConnectAsync("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/api/setup/importwizard/checkUpdates/").Wait()
  End Sub

  Private Async Function ConnectAsync(uri As String) As Task
        Thread.Sleep(1000)

        Dim WebSocket As ClientWebSocket = Nothing

        Try

              WebSocket = New ClientWebSocket
              Await WebSocket.ConnectAsync(New Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None)

              'Await Task.WhenAll(ReceiveAsync(WebSocket), SendAsync(WebSocket))
              Await Task.WhenAll(ReceiveAsync(WebSocket))

        Catch ex As Exception
              Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message)
        Finally
              If WebSocket IsNot Nothing Then
                    WebSocket.Dispose()
              End If

              Debug.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Websocket closed.")
        End Try
  End Function
```

Response From Server

> Laravel development server started on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   [Wed Oct  4 16:15:05 2017] 127.0.0.1:59590 Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)

[Response From Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO4H8.png)

Comment: does the server support websockets at that address?

Comment: Right. Thanks for the tip. Silly me. I'm gonna ask my team. xD

Comment: so what is the solution? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the WebSocket Server `ws://127.0.0.1:8000`

On this, you're using the Laravel HTTP Server

Change it to this: `ws://127.0.0.1:6001`

*(This is the default port, or change it to the one you're currently using)*