# Malformed HTTP Request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, postman

I am building a Laravel back-end API. The API has been implemented and I have tested all the necessary methods and routes. I am now busy creating some test-requests using Postman however I keep getting a 'Malformed HTTP Request' Error in Laravel.

The server side verification is done using Laravel Passport, below is the generated HTTP code from Postman

```
POST /api/my_data_url HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer oauth_key_goes_here
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "value_1": 123,
    "value_2": 123,
    "value_3": 123
}
```

I have had a look at the JSON:API standard however it is not necessary for the purposes of this app, it would be overkill as I am not creating a public API. This is my own app I will be using. On the controller side I merely want it to echo so it looks like this currently:

```
/**
* Store a newly created resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function store(Request $request)
  {
     return response()->json($request->json()->all(), 200);
  }
```

My end goal is to merely pass some sensor data to a Laravel API and use the appropriate controller method to verify and save it to a database. What am I missing, it feels like I am making a stupid mistake?

P.S. I know that there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560219/malformed-http-request) with a very similar problem however it doesn't appear as if that question has a solution that will help me.

Comment: What's the actual value of `$request->json()->all()`? You can use `dd($request->json()->all());` to see what's happening. I suggest you to learn how to debug your application with `xdebug`, there are a lot of tutorials out there and is an essential tool for developers.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte dd reveals nothing, it never fires. The postman console says that there is an "Error: Socket hang up"

Comment: If I remove the JSON body content then the request goes through and the server replies with a Code 200 "OK".

Comment: If I remove the JSON body and place the same parameters in the URL then it reaches the Laravel back-end without error and I can access the values.

Comment: Did you put the body as `raw -> JSON (application/json)` in postman?

Comment: No I specified a content-type header with application/json

Comment: This is the only thing that appears in the body: ```{
    "value_1": 123,
    "value_2": 123,
    "value_3": 123
}```

Comment: Try again with raw -> JSON (application/json)

Comment: Must it look like this ```content: application/json,
{     "value_1": 123,     "value_2": 123,     "value_3": 123 }```

Comment: https://ibb.co/C749JbD Here is a screenshot of Postman

Comment: Remove this "content: application/json" part, makes no sense to use this. You can set content type in the header tab

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yes that is set. The header content type is specified as application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought my original answer was detailed enough as it is merely a configuration error. I will attempt a second answer that is more detailed here. Please note I am using the Linux-based desktop application, I cannot comment on other versions as I do not use them. My Laravel application was also built using Laravel 6.

My error was caused by incorrect request authorization settings. The steps below allowed me to correct the issue.

After you have opened the Postman application do the following:

1. Create a request in Postman by clicking on the `Create a request` label on the right-hand side of the start page of the desktop application
2. You will now be in the request creation tab. Within this, there are multiple tabs to allow you to configure parts of your request. e.g. `Params`, `Authorization` etc.
3. Navigate to the `Authorization` tab and change the Type dropdown to match the authorization schema your Laravel application uses.

These were the steps I took to fix the issue.

Comment: For me, I had simply forgotten to send the Content-Length header.

Answer (score -1):

I eventually figured out what it was months later. My Postman configuration was incorrect. In the Postman settings I had configured the incorrect HTTP authentication scheme, so all my requests were "Malformed" because they contained a different security mechanism than that which Laravel knew. Once I corrected this and changed it from what it was to OAuth2 with a bearer token, my requests came through beautifully!

Comment: You have to post how to solve the issue by changing the settings

Comment: Please what were the steps you took?

Comment: @MohamedRaza See the more detailed second answer.

Comment: @Buchi See my new answer

Comment: @BenjaminBeer unfortunately that didn't work for me. After debugging i figured out my issue was not from postman because whenever I visit 127.0.0.1:port I get a message of Segmentation fault (core dumped), and then the server is restarted in a new port. This error happens only in the project folder as when I created another project it worked just fine. Is there a way to revive this old folder to work fine? thank you

Comment: @Buchi There could be any number of reasons that that specific error occurs. I would recommend you perhaps create a separate question with all the details related to your problem.